# Identify master broker using JMX in ActiveMQ or Fuse AMQ?

Tags: activemq-classic, jmx, jbossfuse, amq

Is it possible to identify the "master" broker in an ActiveMQ/Fuse AMQ master/slave configuration, using JMX, or perhaps a different mechanism? We're creating a dashboard and want to show visually which server is actively handling traffic.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out :-)

**ObjectName**:    `org.apache.activemq:type=Broker,brokerName=amq`

**AttributeName**: `Slave`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have two nodes. They are configured in "[Shared File System Master Slave](http://activemq.apache.org/shared-file-system-master-slave.html)".
JMX shows both node as Slave=false.
So I checked log file to see who made "lock" on shared file system.

```
Database /dir1/activemq-db/lock is locked by another server. This broker is now in slave mode waiting a lock to be acquired | org.apache.activemq.store.SharedFileLocker | main
```